# Understanding how to fit euro style half overlay hinges

Tags: cabinetry, door, hinges

I am trying to plan this build of a small cabinet with a single door at the bottom.

[image: Cabinet door overlaying the carcass]

As you can see the door, when closed, should only partially cover the carcass. Carcass is 3/4" and I would like to get roughly half of it covered (9 or 10mm).

I am reading about half-overlay hinges but it seems that they have a specific application (namely side-to-side cabinets with single panel). Also, when looking online I see graphs with a multitude of letters and measures which base the overlay on the distance you drill the hinge hole.

This is an example:

[image: Blum hinges]

From the graph on the left I guess that if I want a 9.5mm overlay, I need to bore the hole at 3mm from the edge (i.e., 3mm + 17.5mm to the center) and I need to get a 4.5mm high cruciform plate. What are **P** and **S** in that picture? Can I use the half overlay to get a similar overlay?

Other diagrams I find online are even more confusing (someone use **H**, **D** and **K**)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the end a normal concealed hinge from HAFELE did the trick. I guess a blum hinge would have obtained the same result. These kind of hinges have a decent range of adjustment so even if the layout specifies 9mm overlay, it can be easily adjusted to go from 8 to 10 and be extremely precise.

This is the one I went for:
[image: Hafele PDF catalogue snip]

Reading from the table on the right, drilling the hole 5mm from the edge will give you a 9mm overlay.